# .htaccess prettyurl with parameters can't make it work

Tags: .htaccess, pretty-urls

I'm trying to make a prettyurl like
from:
example.com/index.php?key=test&lang=eng
to
example.com/test/eng

I've searched a lot of code samples on the net but I can't seem to make it work. This is what I'm working on right now.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\$ index.php?key=$1&lang=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Use the `QSA` flag (Query-string append)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to escape the `$` symbol. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?key=([^&]+)&lang=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRUle ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?key=$1&lang=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. You can check the site: http://181.224.143.175/~devplus0/index.php?key=asd&lang=qwe

Comment: @TümerKoloğlu if you have stuff before the `index.php`, you need to add it into the condition, e.g. `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+devplus0/index\.php\?key=([^&]+)&lang=([^&\ ]+)`

Comment: @TümerKoloğlu the htaccess file is in the devplus0 folder?

Comment: yep it's in that folder

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. Now it's working. It was my bad. Thank you very much for your help.